# Can I drive an electric car that has been left on before Yom Tov if food was placed on the batteries before Yom Tov?

Tags: halacha-theory, yom-tov, cooking-bishul

DISCLAIMER:  I was referring to what I saw on the Chabad article(the first one linked to as "Yom Tov Laws") I am not considering at all Yom Kippur, I meant Yom Tov in terms of the idea of "work for food" is allowed for festivals.

I was wondering if driving an electric vehicle on Yom Tov would be allowed if the battery of the car is on from before Yom Tov and has a package to cook food filled with something that needs cooking placed on it before Yom Tov. I saw that you are allowed to cook on Yom Tov with an existing flame and enhance an existing flame. The way I see it, the batteries are being used from before Yom Tov are an existing flame and then driving would be enhancing the flame. I know this might be problematic with how it appears for other Jews, so if someone added a sign to the car saying that they were cooking food on the batteries, would it then be allowed? If the previous is allowed, how hot would the batteries have to be to be considered a flame, or is the fact of the electricity considered a flame by itself?

[Yom Tov Laws](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/708510/jewish/Laws-of-Yom-Tov.htm)

[Enhancing a Flame](https://www.cor.ca/view/169/cooking_on_yom_tov.html#:%7E:text=On%20Yom%20Tov%2C%20it%20is,Yom%20Tov%20purpose%2C%20including%20cooking.)

Comment: You're not even allowed to ride a horse on Yom Tov, so while I don't have a source for you, I think driving of any kind is pretty clearly assur

Comment: This is impossible to answer without the specific details of the engineering of the vehicle. The technology is changing in ways that have never been faced in previous generations and until you actually see a final product in this arena, it is impossible to assess whether something would be permissible.

Comment: @JoshK animals are for a specific reason which doesn't apply to cars and we don't make up new gezeiras

Comment: @Josh K, I was referring to what I saw on Chabad article(the first one linked to as "Yom Tov Laws", I was not considering at all Yom Kippur, I meant Yom Tov in terms of the idea of work for food being allowed.

Comment: To the extent that using the batteries is using a flame, putting food there wouldn't help you. One may use flame on Yom Tov even not for food purposes.

Comment: Could you please explain further for me? Does this mean that this would be allowed?